# Angular 1 common service/module/library for multiple "apps"

Tags: angularjs

I can't describe it very well but: 
I have one angular app for "one" functionality. 
E.q. I have "campaigns" functionality. Add, Edit, Display all, display in another way.

For add and edit I have that same app and controller and context etc. 
For rest I have different folders with app, controller, context, config, eventHanlder etc.

But all of them have simillar code in ~70%. 
It is context with download and upload data via $http to ASP.NET WebAPI project. 
And few methods in controller.

I want "merge" it into one but I cant don't want merge these functions into one app because they have different "view".

So I was thinking about:

1. Make "routing" app for these simillar apps.

   - one context, config, and controller same in more than half
   - some different options so it won't be "SoC"?
2. Move common from "context, config, controller" to another files/apps and inject them to concrete controller.

But I don't know how to do it. 
I know I can "factory" method to app inside it config but I want these "services" be indepentent to controllers and apps. As different app in different catalog. So I can inject them via controller.

How it is possible?

Yeah I really new in Angular ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:**

I would advise to look at the [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) module.  This module allows you to define url routes to states with views and nested states/views.  Very useful for anything more than a single page app.

**Question 2:**

Sounds like you're talking about setting up a few `angular.modules` that depend on one another.

In general you would group related services, controllers, configs into a module.  If another module needs to use one of those, you make that module depend on the other.

Example:

```
// myApp.foo module
angular.module('myApp.foo', [])
.factory('Foo', function(){
    return {
        data: {
            foo: 'angularjs is cool!';
        },
        doStuff: function(){
        }
    };
})
.controller('FooController', function($scope, Foo){
    $scope.foo = Foo.data.foo;
    Foo.doStuff();
});

// myApp.bar module
angular.module('myApp.bar', ['myApp.foo']) // notice dependency on myApp.foo
.factory('Bar', function(Foo){             // you can inject Foo because of dependency
    return {
        data: {
            bar: 'using angular modules helps us organize'
        },
        doStuff: {
        },
        doOtherStuff: {
            Foo.doStuff();
        }
    };
})
.controller('BarController', function($scope, Bar, Foo){ // you can inject Foo into controllers too
    $scope.foo = Foo.data.foo;
    $scope.bar = Bar.data.bar;

    $scope.doFoo = Foo.doStuff;
    $scope.doBar = Bar.doStuff;
    $scope.doOtherBar = Bar.doOtherStuff;
});
```

It is always good practice to think about and develop your modules in a way that they can be reused in different projects.

**Update:** (RE: question about /AppCommon, /App1, /App2, /App3)

Just make your service in: `/AppCommon/my-service.srv.js`*
It would look something like:

```
angular.module('MyCompany.Common', [])
.factory('CommonService', function($http){
    return {
        doStuff: function(){
            $http.get('/some-url').then(function(res){
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And in your /App1, /App2, /App3 projects:

1. Include that js file into your HTML:

`<script src="/AppCommon/my-service.srv.js></script>`

2. Inject the `MyCompany.Common` module into the areas of the apps where you need it.

`angular.module('App1', ['MyCompany.Common']);`

3. Inject the `CommonService` into the app's controllers/services where you need it.

   angular.module('App1', ['MyCompany.Common'])
   .controller('App1Controller', function($scope, CommonService){
   });

*Note: You can name your javascript file however you want.  I have found it very helpful to include .srv in files containing services, .ctrl in files containing controllers, .drv in files containing directives, .tpl in template files, etc...  This goes along with the best practice of having one *thing* per file.

Comment: Its good option to create module that can be reused but how I can do it? In your example you have same "app" name for all of them. In my project I have folders "/App1, /App2, /App3" and I want make service that I can inject to controler. The servcie should be placec in /AppCommon and using $http. Can you make such a example?